# Migrating cube from Microsoft SQL Server Analysis Services (SSAS) to Oracle Hyperion Essbase

Tags: oracle, ssas, hyperion, essbase

I'm looking for a tool or at the very least a tutorial that would ease the conversion/migration of a SSAS cube to a Oracle Essbase cube.

I have researched in multiple different places and I can't seems to find any information regarding migration from SSAS into Essbase. Most information online has to do with migrations of cubes from Essbase into SSAS. Please let me know if there is anything that would help me out in performing such a migration.

Answer (score 0):

There's no tool that can migrate you automatically from one to the other. Further, SSAS and Essbase are quite different from each other. The good news is that you probably have all of the relational data that you need in order to build the cube. The key to this migration, however, is going to be designing a "sensible" Essbase cube based on the existing SSAS cube. In short, this means architecting a solution that makes sense, your users will find useful, and is maintainable. You might find it worthwhile to discuss your needs with a consultant so that for the least part they can guide your design.